# Differentiation of $x^TAx$ (Multivariate Calculus)

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, linear-transformations

Suppose $A$ is an $n\times n$ symmetric matrix. Consider a function $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $$f(x) = \langle Ax , x \rangle = x^TAx\quad\quad\text{for all}~~~ x \in \mathbb{R}^n$$ I want to find its derivative, i.e. $Df$ .

Most probably, it can be done by expanding $x^TAx$ by usual matrix multiplication. But I'm looking for a procedure which doesn't involve this sort of expansion. However, any elementary proof will help. Thanks in advance. Sorry if someone had asked this problem before.

Comment: Please check https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3019859/derivative-of-inner-product

Comment: Answer of this will be 2Ax. For more intuitive explanation on this, check out the page 925-The mathematical appendix of the Basic Econometrics by Damodar N Gujrati. Link attached.

http://www.uop.edu.pk/ocontents/gujarati_book.pdf

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of notations and methods used by different authors in discussing vector calculus.

One simple approach to computing derivatives like this is to expand out the function $f(x+\Delta x)$ and truncate the result to $f(x)$ plus a term that is linear in $\Delta x$.  The coefficient of $\Delta x$ is then the derivative. Higher-order terms involving $\Delta x$ are ignored.

$(x+\Delta x)^{T}A(x+\Delta x)=x^{T}Ax+(\Delta x)^{T}Ax+x^{T}A\Delta x+\Delta x^{T}A\Delta x.$

Note that $\Delta x^{T}Ax=x^{T}A^{T}\Delta x$.  Thus

$(x+\Delta x)^{T}A(x+\Delta x)=x^{T}Ax+x^{T}(A+A^{T})\Delta x+\Delta x^{T}A\Delta x$

The $\Delta x^{T}A \Delta x$ term is higher order and can be ignored in computing the gradient.  The derivative is the coefficient of $\Delta x$ in the linear term, $x^{T}(A+A^{T})$.

However, the gradient is always presented as a column vector, so

$\nabla (x^{T}Ax)=(A+A^{T})x.$

If $A$ is symmetric, this is commonly written as $2Ax$.